# Why does Hello world not print in vim but it works in tty?

Tags: c++, linux, vim, terminal, makefile

In Vim I enter the command `:w | make`. My Makefile looks like this:

```
all:
    g++ -o main main.cpp
    ./main
```

main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello world!";
}
```

Vim output says:

```
"main.cpp" 6L, 88C written
:!make 2>&1| tee /tmp/ve16mwu/0
g++ -o main maincpp
./main
(1 of 3): g++ -o main main.cpp
Press ENTER or type command to continue_
```

Now after I quit Vim and run the executable: `$ ./main` then the output shows up fine in the terminal.

If I put add a newline `\n` to the line like this: `"Hello world!\n"` then it shows in Vim's output just fine.

Apparently, in Vim, the output won't show your last line of text if it doesn't have `\n` on the end. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You forgot to flush. Hopefully you remembered to wipe though.

Comment: Hah, ok. You'll have to forgive me. What is and how do I flush?

Comment: @Slyps **no**. `\n` [does not flush](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

Comment: My apologies. Always assumed it does. I'm ever using `\n` in console context. I may accept my death penalty now

Comment: I apologize. I left out that I actually write this in vim command:`w | make`

Comment: This worked just fine for me (after I fixed the indentation in the Makefile) with vim 7.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 and g++ 4.8.2.

Comment: @Gene I'm not sure what worked for you. Are you referring to the configuration in my post? If so, please help me! haha What part of the indentation should I fix?

Comment: The indentation was wrong when copying and pasting the makefile from here. I got a completely different error. -- Do you have a custom .vimrc? If so can you include it in your post?

Comment: Thanks, Gene. Here are the files I'm using in this post (I hope 7z is ok): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ObkUHX0n2YVXo1R0g3bU9Pdm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I noticed I forgot return 0; but that wasn't the fix. I found the "endl" function to flush.

Answer (score 0):

**endl** From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/):

> **Insert newline and flush**
>
> Inserts a new-line character and *flushes* the stream.

So the code would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```